# Working with Mvvmcross and Xibs

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to get mvvmcross working for some iOS development and I can get it working if I had code my views adding all the necessary controls in code. This works, but is a huge pain to develop that way. I want to work with the xib files in xcode to define the interface, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. I have a view class like this:

```
[Register("FirstView")]
public partial class FirstView : MvxViewController 
{
    public FirstView () : base("FirstView",null) 
    {
    }

    public FirstView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
    }
}
```

I add an iphone view called "FirstView.xib", open it in xcode and the first problem I run into is that it's created a view, not a view controller, so I can set the class to `FirstView`. So I delete the view, add a UIViewController and it lets me set the class to `FirstView`. Then I drag a view onto my view controller and add a textbox, a label and a button. I quit xcode and Xamarin does its thing and creates the other half of my partial class. However, when I try and run the code in the iPhone simulator, it doesn't work. It starts up and then immediately quits without ever showing my view.

I see a whole bunch of stuff in the application output window in Xamarin studio, perhaps this is relevant?

> 2013-06-06 10:47:13.666 MyAppIPhoneUI[26190:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
>   2013-06-06 10:47:13.668 MyAppIPhoneUI[26190:c07] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:   0.10 Navigate requested
>   2013-06-06 10:47:13.691 MyAppIPhoneUI[26190:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.13 Request is null - assuming this is a TabBar type situation where ViewDidLoad is called during construction... patching the request now - but watch out for problems with virtual calls during construction
>   2013-06-06 10:47:13.697 MyAppIPhoneUI[26190:c07] mvx: Warning:   0.13 Exception masked NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>         at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000]

Any idea what the problem might be? Is it actually possible to define my view in a xib and still use mvvmcross? I've seen slodge's YouTube where he uses a xib to define a UITableCellView, but not an entire view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the trace the 'doesn't start' issue is to do with:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel

I'm not sure what's causing that - it's hard to tell from the trace and description - if you put a sample project somewhere then someone from mvx can take a look.

---

Alternatively there are a few more up to date videos for working with XIBs

These are contained in this N+1 index - http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

In particular, see:

- FirstView/XIB work starting at 22:40 in http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=UC2r4mmj3UI#t=22m40
- Several views in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0Eww89c9DM&feature=youtube_gdata (although not sure why I said I couldn't build on the Mac at the time - may have been due to setup/activation issues :/)

Comment: Huh? Odd. I deleted my view class and the xib and followed (almost) exactly what you did in the video to add a view controller and it worked. Maybe the problem was with me initially having a view rather than a view controller. I'd started watching that video before, but hadn't got that far into it. Thanks. One weird thing I have is that my solution in Xamarin now shows two copies of FirstModel.designer.cs and two copies of FirstModel.xib (one in the view folder and one in the root folder), which is rather odd.

Comment: I guess the chances are the previous problem will have been to do with some 'owner' or 'first responder' or other setting hidden within the xib - 4 years of working with these things and I still don't understand them... the two copies of designer files will hopefully go away if you restart XS - but by all means log that as a bug with xamarin support (it does need fixing)

Comment: Thanks again Stuart. I'm just starting into iOS development and it does feel like xcode is actively fighting me every step of the way! Having done a lot in the past with WPF, I really appreciate your work with mvvmcross for helping me bridge the gap with something familiar.